# What Seatpost Is This?

Tags: seatpost

I saw a picture of a seatpost that I'd like to buy but cannot find after much browsing. Unfortunately I no longer have a photo but have this information about it. Can someone identify it?

- Black. Not sure if it was carbon or not.
- Had a stylized "C" on it.
- Was described as a Campagnolo C-Record seatpost (although I have never seen any Campy seatpost like this before).
- Traditional round (possibly 25mm) post which transitioned to an aero profile
- Saddle rail attachment was the most distinguishing feature. It was composed of what appeared to be disks with a concave furrow around their perimeter (like a clothline pulley) on either side of the post. The bottom of the saddle rails rested on this. Then there was some other type of attachment (was hard to see detail) on the upper side of each saddle rail.

It was a thing of beauty.

Comment: Please leave a comment when downvoting. I'm new to this forum and so I don't know why I got a downvote.

Comment: I down-voted because this information is too limited/specific to be of long term use to the general SE population. A more appropriate question would maybe ask how to identify seatposts and other components in general, or maybe the potential benefits of different saddle attachment/adjustment hardware. Sorry if it is discouraging. Our FAQ section is very helpful in this regard. Also: (http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/748/if-you-are-going-to-downvote-why-not-add-feedback-as-to-why-you-downvoted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly you were thinking of [Ciasta aero seatposts](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Ciasta%20Aero%20blade%20carbon%20seat%20post&sugexp=chrome,mod%3D19&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&authuser=0&ei=AMnAUPKrAsXZ0QHZz4HwCw&biw=1148&bih=802&sei=AcnAUIOFHauI0QGiloDYDg) which has a similar logo?

Something like this perhaps...
[image]

Comment: Yes! That is logo and the picture is of a very similar seatpost. Thank you very much - I've been searching on web without success. Upvoted and accepted as answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good photo of a C Record post, [here](http://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=96db8eb6-682f-4db7-87af-17d687641766).

It sounds like you had a knock off C-Record post. The head you describe is different, and the C logo was sometimes used to infer Campy, when a product was not Campy.

The logo in the linked pic is what should be on a C Record post.

Comment: No, definetely not that post. More aero, black, and the saddle rail attachment was as I described and not the traditional above/below rail clamps like on Campy seatposts. I wish I could find the photo again! :)